# Python Flask Lock while processing API requests

Tags: flask

I have a Flask app which serves API endpoints. I need to lock a certain endpoint so that each customer can only have one request to this endpoint running at a time.

I know I could simply write the customer id to a database at the start of the request and remove it at the end, with a unique constraint.

Another alternative would be to use a plugin such as https://github.com/TheWaWaR/flask-redlock/tree/master/flask_redlock.

Is there a standard way to handle this?

Comment: Interesting problem - do you expect to hold subsequent requests from a given customer in a queue of some sort, or respond with something like `429 Too Many Requests`? Some other course of action perhaps? While I don’t necessarily think it’s absolutely essential for this particular question, a bit more about the use case might give leeway to answerers to provide insight to even more alternatives, like message queues or in-memory databases (if your architecture/use case allows) among others.